# Behaviour of poll() in Kafka Consumer API

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have built a consumer using Kafka Consumer API , the way this consumer is supposed to work is fetch 'n' messages from the topic , and process them in concurrent fashion and every thread then commits offset as well for the message it has processed . So the poll() call in the API is dependent on the time which is set , Is there any way we can poll() for the next batch only after all the threads have processed the previous batch and committed the offset ?

Comment: can you show the code and you want to consume records only at particular time?

Comment: The kafka consumer is not thread safe. See https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#multithreaded If you want to use threads, keep one thread do polling and offset committing, and fan out the work to other threads in a thread pool. Java has many mechanisms to be notified when a thread in a thread pool has completed.